# MyBatis is not closing Prepared Statement

Tags: spring-mvc, mariadb, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper, mybatis-configuration

I'm using mybatis 3.1 with spring 4.3 to connect Maria db. In my application I am using only 2 prepared statement (callable statement type). But after few hours of the running of the app it starts giving error "Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements (current value:16382)". I'm using SqlSessionTemplate for getting mapper, not able to understand where statements are getting opened and closed or getting closed at all?

Comment: And you expect an answer without showing code, configuration in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Got the issues..was using SIMPLE Executor type instead of RESUSE